# Is vector linear interpolation same as linear extrapolation?

Tags: c, vector, interpolation

Having a  linear interpolation (lerp) function looking like:

```
/// Performs a linear interpolation between two vectors. (@p v1 toward @p v2)
///  @param[out]    dest    The result vector. [(x, y, x)]
///  @param[in]     v1      The starting vector.
///  @param[in]     v2      The destination vector.
///  @param[in]     t       The interpolation factor. [Limits: 0 <= value <= 1.0]
inline void dtVlerp(float* dest, const float* v1, const float* v2, const float t)
{
    dest[0] = v1[0]+(v2[0]-v1[0])*t;
    dest[1] = v1[1]+(v2[1]-v1[1])*t;
    dest[2] = v1[2]+(v2[2]-v1[2])*t;
}
```

Here by linear extrapolation  I mean finding a position on line (see the drawing)
[image]

will it work for linear extrapolation (say providing `coef > 1` or less than `0`)?

Comment: Yes, the only difference between linear interpolation and linear extrapolation is that in interpolation, you estimate the value between known data points, and in extrapolation, outside the known range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, extrapolation is the same as interpolation (in this context, at least).

If you recall from high-school geometry, any line is defined by an equation of the form:

```
y = mx + c
```

where `m` is the gradient and `c` is an offset (specifically, the y-axis intercept).  If you look at your code above, you'll see each dimension has an equation of the form:

```
dest = v1 + (v2-v1)*t
```

which is the same!  We've simply substituted as follows:

- `y   <--  dest`
- `x   <--  t`
- `m   <--  (v2-v1)`
- `c   <--  v1`

So you can set `t` to any value (not just in the range [0,1]) and get a unique point somewhere on the line.